# Outlook 2016 HTML email "width: auto;" being ignored

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

HTML emails in Outlook 2016 is ignoring `width: auto;`.  This doesn't happen with the latest Outlook 365 email client; it works as expected using Outlook 365 email client.  I tried searching for a solution using a Google search; however, the the issues/solutions reported seem to be a bit different than the 
issue I'm having.  Also, my HTML authoring skills is very limited currently to adapt a solution for my case.

I was hoping someone could offer the simplest solution to achieve the same result as `width: auto;` in my html code below.  I would prefer to keep the code as close to the example I have as possible.

```html
<HTML>

<BODY><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtWEB9L-ynY " target="_blank" /><span
        style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif">Final Unboxing Video and Channel
        Announcements<font size="1"><br><br></font><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GtWEB9L-ynY/maxresdefault.jpg"
            height="315" width: auto;></a><br>
        <font size=1>Source: <a
                href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtWEB9L-ynY">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtWEB9L-ynY<br></a>
        </font><br>
        <font size="2">Support The 8-Bit Guy on Patreon: <a class="comurl" href="https://www.patreon.com/8BitGuy1"
                target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://www.patreon.com/8BitGuy1</a><br> Visit my website: <a
                class="comurl" href="http://www.the8bitguy.com/" target="_blank"
                rel="nofollow">http://www.the8bitguy.com/</a><br>
    </span></font><br></BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: HTML e-mail is a nightmare.  You pretty much have to hard-code all sizes and hope for the best.  There is no meaningful standard for how mail clients render HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thanks.  But, I noticed there are existing work-arounds to Outlook HTML issues.  I was hoping there is a work-around for mine too.  They all seem to be related to Outlook 2016 and auto width.  Having a fixed width isn't something I can use since the images are different proportions every time.  I just need to constrain the size while maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Try `object-fit: cover`?  Why not use `sddefault.jpg` instead, which gives you a guaranteed 4:3 aspect ratio?

Comment: I tried `object-fit: cover` instead of `width: auto`.  That did not make a difference.  90% of all the images I use are 16:9; and, prefer not to have any letterboxing.

Comment: You'd still need to set a width if you wanted to use `cover`.  I don't know if `object-fit: cover` works in e-mail clients or not.  Realistically, you're going to have to set a width if you want this to work.  It's not as if Outlook is the only place you're having trouble, no doubt.

Comment: Also, maybe I'm not understanding entirely what you're trying to do, but that HTML... is it actually your HTML?  Because it's invalid.  You'd need to put your styles in a `style` attribute.  And, if you just leave the width alone, it will auto-set based on the height usually.  (Again though, e-mail is all sorts of messed up...)

Comment: Sorry. I just updated my question to include an actual html example that works correctly in Outlook 365 (and other email readers I've tried), but not Outlook 2016. It probably won't help though if you don't have Outlook 2016 to test against.

Comment: Alright, your `width: auto` isn't doing anything... needs to be `style="width: auto"`, but I don't think that helps you any.